# JQuery height after scripts load

Tags: jquery

I have this situation where I have a bunch of divs that get populated mostly from templates. My data comes from many sources but I am only having trouble with the div (div3) that has data coming from a script. I am trying to get the height for this div but it seems that theJQuery .height() and the .css('height') get the values **after the site has rendered but NOT after the script data has returned**, therefore I am getting a height of 0 even though there is data coming to populate my div. The data comes from an external source so I have no control over it. Here is what the code looks like:

```
<div class="div1">
    ...some code
    <div class="div2">data comes from DB</div>
    ...some code
    <div class="div3">data comes from script</div>
</div>
<div class="div4">
    ..some code
</div>
```

Any ideas how to get the height for div3? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you also show your jQuery code please?

Comment: Please provide jQuery code as well.

Comment: Kindly check 
http://jsfiddle.net/5qdGA/2/  and 
http://jsfiddle.net/5qdGA/3/
i have no problem with something like this ... post your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this fiddle [scenario](http://jsfiddle.net/ppolyzos/NF2gB/)

Check how the height of the div3 changes.

Maybe a reason why the height stays at '0px' is that you have declared it in css for .div3 and you forget to remove it when the data comes from your script.